# Blocking web requests while step code is running in cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, webrick

I'm using Cucumber + Selenium for testing some Rails code. In that configuration I'm sometimes running into an issue where some extra resources / delayed request gets loaded in the browser after the first step (requesting the page) has finished and the second step is running.

Unfortunately the code is not thread-safe and the extra request and the next step cannot run at the same time.

Is there any way to lock the webrick from accepting any requests until a specific section of feature/step code is complete? Does cucumber or webrick expose any relevant synchronisation?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is have the first request look for something from the extra resources so that it doesn't finish until they have loaded. If you use Capybara you will find it is very good at doing this.

Another thing you could do is use the rack driver instead, as this won't load the javascript that your using to load your extra resources. If you don't need the extra resources for your test why load them :)

Comment: I need something more generic that that unfortunately. I want some reusable step to say "you can't handle any requests why this is running", wherever it's used. (this cannot rely on specific resources) I'm not sure what you mean by the rack driver? Could you expand on that?

Comment: The default stack for cuking with rails is, Cucumber, Capybara and Rack (https://rack.github.io/). Rack provides a minimal interface between webservers that use ruby and ruby frameworks e.g. Rails. Capybara acts as a middleman between your Cukes and your browser. You can configure Capybara to talk to your webserver using rack, selenium or a number of other drivers. Rack is the simplest and fastest talks directly to the webserver but doesn't support javascript. Selenium is much slower, does support javascript and can use real or headless browsers.